# Updating MySQL table from JSON using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, json

Hi all and thanks for your patience,

I'm trying to write a cron job to update currencies rate in our MySQL database. The JSON data that I'm receiving looks like this;

```
{
  "disclaimer": "Exchange rates are provided for informational purposes only, and do not constitute financial advice of any kind. Although every attempt is made to ensure quality, NO guarantees are given whatsoever of accuracy, validity, availability, or fitness for any purpose - please use at your own risk. All usage is subject to your acceptance of the Terms and Conditions of Service, available at: ",
  "license": "Data sourced from various providers with public-facing APIs; copyright may apply; resale is prohibited; no warranties given of any kind. Bitcoin data provided by. All usage is subject to your acceptance of the License Agreement available at:",
  "timestamp": 1427914861,
  "base": "CAD",
  "rates": {
    "AED": 2.908081,
    "AFN": 45.794285,
    "ALL": 103.179929,
    "AMD": 373.363817,
    "ANG": 1.416823,
    "AOA": 85.603315,
    "ARS": 6.986543,
    "AUD": 1.041048,
    "AWG": 1.42113,
    "AZN": 0.829254,
    "BAM": 1.437242,
    "BBD": 1.583432,
    "BDT": 61.66817,
    "BGN": 1.437963,
    "BHD": 0.298493,
    "BIF": 1246.009421,
    "BMD": 0.791716,
    "BND": 1.080918,
    "BOB": 5.468926,
    "BRL": 2.518805,
    "BSD": 0.791716,
    "BTC": 0.0032649636,
    "BTN": 49.501403,
    "BWP": 7.855039,
    "BYR": 11644.270337,
    "BZD": 1.581753,
    "CAD": 1,
    "CDF": 733.551108,
    "CHF": 0.76573,
    "CLF": 0.019475,
    "CLP": 490.205281,
    "CNY": 4.895048,
    "COP": 2038.824734,
    "CRC": 422.26163,
    "CUC": 0.791716,
    "CUP": 0.791726,
    "CVE": 80.458447,
    "CZK": 20.263721,
    "DJF": 140.548137,
    "DKK": 5.492318,
    "DOP": 35.391341,
    "DZD": 77.203651
  }
}
```

Since the table already exist, all I want to do is to update the currencies that we have in the table, not all currencies that the JSON file is giving me.  We only have 7 currencies in our table (it can change depending on if we accept more currencies or less). This is the code I come up with;

```
<?php


define("_SITE_SECURED_FILES_",realpath(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../../../")."\Secured_Files");

// Database Credentials
require_once(_SITE_SECURED_FILES_."\Database\credentials.mysql.php");

// Open Exchange Rates Credentials
require_once(_SITE_SECURED_FILES_."\Open_Exchange_Rates\credentials.openexchangerates.php");

// Requested file
// Could also be e.g. 'currencies.json' or 'historical/2011-01-01.json'
$file = 'latest.json';
$base_currency = 'CAD';

// Open CURL session
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://openexchangerates_org/api/{$file}?app_id={$appId}&base={$base_currency}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// Get the data:
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Decode JSON response:
$exchangeRates = json_decode($json);

foreach($exchangeRates['rates'] as $key => $value) {
if($value) {

//how to use json array to insert data in Database
    mysqli_query($mysql,"UPDATE currencies SET dblRateCAD = '".$value."' WHERE strCode = '".$exchangeRates['rates']."' LIMIT 1");
    }
}


?>
```

Right now, it doesn't work. I'm getting

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on line 29: foreach($exchangeRates['rates'] as $key => $value) {

Comment: Because `json_decode` gives you an Object not an Array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: The JSON you are receiving contains the exchange rates as properties of an object, not as an array. Since the `stdClass` object doesn't include an iterator you need to extract the rate by reading each property you need. For seven that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array just use `json_decode($json, true)` and modify your query to `"UPDATE currencies SET dblRateCAD = '".$value."' WHERE strCode = '". $key ."'`

```
// Decode JSON response:
$exchangeRates = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($exchangeRates['rates'] as $key => $value) {
if($value) {

//how to use json array to insert data in Database
    mysqli_query($mysql,"UPDATE currencies SET dblRateCAD = '".$value."' WHERE strCode = '". $key ."' LIMIT 1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is decoding to an object, not an array. And even if it was an array, you'd be using it incorrectly:

```
foreach($exchangeRates['rates'] as $key => $value) {
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---array
    mysqli_query([..snip..]WHERE strCode = '".$exchangeRates['rates']."' LIMIT 1")
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--same array
```

An array used in string context is the literal word `Array`. e.g.

```
$foo = array();
echo "This is an $foo"; // outputs 'This is an Array'
```

And as written, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: It's a cron job and this file is not accessible from the webpage, is it a big issue? I guess the answer should be that I should learn how to prevent SQL injection, but for the moment, can it be an issue? Thanks.